# DynamoDB use logical evaluation In key condition expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible in DynamoDB to use a logical evaluation on the sort key in a key condition expression?

For example, on a table with partition key ‘department’ and sort key ‘user’, is it possible to build a key condition expression on a query that looks like:

```
department eq ‘finance’ and (user eq ‘123’ OR user eq ‘321’)
```

Comment: I was about ready to post the exact question and found your question here. After looking at the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html, I don't think you can do a compound sort key condition like this. I think the condition on the sort key is a single condition using the operators they document there. They don't mention the logical operations for the sort key under the "Key Condition Expression" section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible to check the keys in condition expressions.

But your example does not have the right syntax. Some comments about the syntax:

1. In DynamoDB, constants (like 'finance' or 123) are never part of the expression, but given in a separate parameter, `ExpressionAttributeValues`, and then each constant is referred in the expression by its name, eg., `:val`. The rationale is that DynamoDB already has a way to encode constants of different types in JSON, there was no reason to invent yet another way to encode these constants inside the expression.
2. Some attribute names are also reserved in expressions, so you can also use `ExpressionAttributeNames` and refer to these names as `#name`. You don't have to do this if the names you chose aren't one of the reserved names.
3. The equality operator is `=`, not `eq`.